How can I make an analysis of a compatibility of two versions of Python to make sure that the migration won’t cause issues
I want to know if there is a procedure or steps to make an analysis of a compatibility of two versions of Python to make sure that the migration won’t cause issues in the system.
What are the main things to be aware? How can I verify eventual problems? What are the most common issues and problems when there is the migration?
I never do this before and I read the what’s new seeing the deprécate  methods but I am really don’t know what is the right way to do it.
I want some Steps to complete this analysis

The best advice would be... JUST DONT... people invented venv and conda for environment management because trying to migrate between 2 Python versions especially when they are 1-2 major updates apart, will cause your code to break. But I will still post an answer based on what I know.
